# O método ou a operação não está implementada c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Não consigo identificar o porquê deste erro, sendo que fiz outros desenvolvimentos com essa lógica e funcionou.

> O método ou a operação não está implementada.

Segue código:

Metódo que inicia os valores:

```
 private void linkLblStatus_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Pedido objPedido = new Pedido();
                RetornoSefaz objRetorno = new RetornoSefaz();
                objPedido.PedEmpresa = Metodos.empresa;
                objPedido.PedNumero = txtNumPedido.Text;
                if (objPedido.ConsultarNFPedido(Metodos.empresa, objPedido.PedNumero) > 0)
                {
                    if (objPedido.pedNFStatus == "Rejeitada" || objPedido.pedNFStatus == "Autorizada")
                    {
                        objRetorno.NFEmpresa = objPedido.PedEmpresa;
                        objRetorno.NFNumero = objPedido.pedNFNumero;
                        objRetorno.NFSerie = objPedido.pedNFSerie;
                        objRetorno.NFCliente = txtCodigo.Text;
                        objRetorno.NFTipo = objPedido.pedNFTipo;
                        List<RetornoSefaz> ListaRetorno = objRetorno.ListarRetornoSefaz();
                        if (ListaRetorno.Count > 0)
                        {
                            FrmStatusNF frmStatus = new FrmStatusNF(ListaRetorno);
                            frmStatus.ShowDialog();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

ListarRetornoSefaz onde está causando o erro:

O erro acontece na linha : `DataTable dt = SqlDAO.ConsultarSQL(strSql, listaParam.ToArray());`

```
public List<RetornoSefaz> ListarRetornoSefaz()
        {
            try
            {
                List<SqlParameter> listaParam = new List<SqlParameter>();
               StringBuilder strSql = new StringBuilder();
                strSql.Append("SELECT * FROM VincoRetornoSefaz WHERE 1=1");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NFEmpresa))
                {
                    strSql.Append(" AND NFEmpresa = @NFEmpresa ");
                    listaParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@NFEmpresa", NFEmpresa));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NFNumero))
                {
                    strSql.Append(" AND NFNumero = @NFNumero ");
                    listaParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@NFNumero", NFNumero));
                }
                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NFSerie))
                {
                    strSql.Append(" AND NFSerie =  @NFSerie");
                    listaParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@NFSerie", NFSerie));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NFCliente))
                {
                    strSql.Append(" AND NFCliente =  @NFCliente ");
                    listaParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@NFCliente", NFCliente));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NFTipo))
                {
                    strSql.Append(" AND NFTipo =  @NFTipo ");
                    listaParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@NFTipo", NFTipo));
                }
                strSql.Append(" ORDER BY NFINDENT DESC ");

                DataTable dt = SqlDAO.ConsultarSQL(strSql, listaParam.ToArray());
                return dt.ToList<RetornoSefaz>();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tentou alterar:
DataTable dt = SqlDAO.ConsultarSQL(strSql, listaParam.ToArray());

Para:
var dt = SqlDAO.ConsultarSQL(strSql, listaParam.ToArray());

Outra coisa, não é preciso criar uma instancia do SqlDAO?

Comment: @RonaldoPeres o formatador do stackoverflow colore a palavra SqlDAO porque não tem como saber se é uma classe ou instância, portanto ele assume que é classe. Pode ser um objeto global ou herdado de uma base. Ou realmente é um erro kkkk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normalmente esse erro ocorre quando você usa o auxílio do Visual Studio para criar membros de uma interface que foi adicionada a uma classe que você criou, dá uma olhada na classe deste `SqlDAO`, tenho quase certeza que vai achar o método `ConsultarSQL` com um `throw NotImplementedException` nele.

Para mais informações sobre essa exceção:
[NotImplementedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception(v=vs.110).aspx)